# Lucene Range Search for .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, lucene

I have Min and Max Value indexed. it should return when the value is between min and max when the search function is called. I'm new to Lucene .NET 4.8.0

**any help will be appreciated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Lucene.Net.Search.NumericRangeQuery`, this query matches numeric values within specific range.

In your case (in Lucene syntax) it would be:

```
max:[value TO *] AND min:[* TO value]
```

Where `value` is your input. If you want to the values to be exclusive - you should use `{` instead of `[`

In Lucene.NET it should be something like this:

```
Query q = NumericRangeQuery.newFloatRange(“fieldName”, new Float(value), float.MaxValue, true, true);
```

And similar for second part, with replacing * to a minimum float value

Comment: I have indexed my Min and Max Value.I will pass one value if it is in that range it should get hit

Comment: @MustafaKunwa yeah, I got it, I propose you a solution